# Why my Indexer is not working?

Tags: c#, indexer

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like
>   arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take
>   parameters.

I have a code like this

```
class StudentMemento
    {
        Student student;
        public Student this[int index]
        {
            get { return student; }
            set { student = new Student { time = DateTime.Now }; }
        }
    }
    class Client
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            StudentMemento s = new StudentMemento();
            Student s1 = s[1];
            Student s2 = s[2];
            Student s3 = s[1];
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

According to the documentation in msdn i should get an instance of Student in the following members s1,s2 because i am returning an object of Student int the Indexer but i am getting a null reference. Can anyone help me understand, why is that so. Thanks

Comment: The `student` field isn't assigned until you call the setter, which you aren't doing in `Main`.

Comment: you need a list or an array of students

Comment: @mcNets i am trying to understand the workings of Indexer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After

```
StudentMemento s = new StudentMemento();
```

s.student will be `null`. The `student` field is only assigned within the indexer setter, so you need to call that before calling the getter e.g.

```
StudentMemento s = new StudentMemento();
s[1] = null;

Student s1 = s[1];
Student s2 = s[2];
Student s3 = s[1];
```

Comment: but when i set s[1]=null, s1 gets an object of Student(). But how is the variable s2 is also getting the value when i have not called a setter on s[2]

Comment: @LijinJohn - There is only one backing field, your indexer doesn't use the `index` parameter at all.